# How can I add @anywhere to my blog?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, twitter

I would really like to add [@anywhere](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere) support to my blog, as my posts usually mention two or three Twitter users.

I'm not much of a code monkey though, and so I'm looking for something that adds @anywhere without me having to do too much configuration.

Is there a plugin available where I can add @anywhere and configure it through the WordPress administration panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Otto's [Simple Twitter Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect). It's pretty amazing, and doesn't require too much configuration.